# Replace iterated output with custom print statement

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, iteration

```
def the(x):
    i = 0
    while i < 6:
        i += x
        print "i equals %s" % i
        if i == 5:
            print "This replaces the 5th iteration"
```

---

I have a loop that increments i by 1, stops at i < 6 and prints a string for every iteration.

I want to remove the 5th iteration ("i equals 5") and replace it with the string: "This replaces the 5th iteration".

What are my options?

Comment: Read up on the full syntax of the `if` statement, specifically the `else` part.

Comment: Geez can I stop being downvoted? How can this be a duplicate, there is no mention of the word decorator? I don't even know what a decorator is

Comment: It is clearly not a duplicate; whoever voted that it is has clearly made a mistake. It doesn't matter though as it would require more votes before it gets closed, and it's unlikely to get those votes. As to why it got downvoted, I am *guessing* that it simply might be because the question is so basic (I personally think the question is perfectly fine for this site).

Comment: Kinda hostile for beginners. The site should have a beginner tag that gives rep to those who answer + special teacher badge.

Comment: Yes, this site could at times be a bit harsh on beginners. I can't say I like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the condition before printing it by using an `else` statement. What you have prints the 5th one before even checking if it's the 5th one. (I added parentheses for print because I use Python 3, should still work in Python 2)

```
def the(x):
    i = 0
    while i < 6:
        i += x
        if i == 5:
            print("This replaces the 5th iteration")
        else:
            print("i equals %s" % i)

>>> the(1)
i equals 1
i equals 2
i equals 3
i equals 4
This replaces the 5th iteration
i equals 6
```

Comment: Thank you Jose, but how does it know to insert and replace the 5th statement in that order?

Comment: @ZaneTribal It is going through a loop and each time adds x to i. So naturally, the next iteration is going to be (current i) + x. Then the next one will add x again. I suggest reading up on iteration and control structures for python to get your head around the details.

Comment: What do you mean? Because you are iterating by 1, and each iteration adds 1 to i, we can conclude that the 5th iteration will have the value 5 for i. So we insert the if `i == 5` statement to check for when i, and thus the iteration, is on 5. When it isn't on 5, it skips over the if statement because the condition is not true, and executes the else code block (print i = whatever).

Comment: @ZaneTribal No problem. Be sure to click that checkmark to accept the answer! We'll both get rep ;)